# Mongoose findOne() returns null just before desired answer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to NodeJS, mongoDB/mongoose. I am trying to render task items from List Model ( I am using mongoDB atlas and have the data saved already) :

```
////////////// TASKS COLLECTION /////////////

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

const Task = mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema);

////////////////// LISTS COLLECTION /////////////////////

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    task: [taskSchema]
});

const List = mongoose.model("list", listSchema);
app.route("/:listName")
    .get((req, res) => {
        let listName = req.params.listName;

        List.findOne({ name: listName }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        })

    })
```

The lists collection looks like this in ATLAS:
[image]

When I try `console.log(result`) i get `null` before i get the desired result:

```
null
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64c68d2cf8cffdb0c232852d"),
  name: 'Today',
  task: [
    {
      name: 'Click the + button to add Task',
      _id: new ObjectId("64c68d2cf8cffdb0c2328525")
    },
    {
      name: 'Click the checkbox to delete a Task',
      _id: new ObjectId("64c68d2cf8cffdb0c2328526")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

So, if i were to try `console.log(result.name)` or `console.log(result.task)` for the same route I get the error:

```
console.log(result.task);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'task')
```

Is this error due to some NodeJS error or Database error. ( I am a beginner so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you calling this route from postman? or some frontend app? are you sure that you are not making two calls with two different listName, one of which probably is invalid?

Comment: No I am building a ToDo list web app myself and i am calling this route by clicking a a link with `href="/Today"`.

Comment: The `null` before the desired result only happens the first time i click the link, if i click the link again i don't get `null` just the result.

Comment: please add your frontend code which is triggering the fetch with your question. I think the problem lies there.

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(req.params.listName)`

Answer (score 0):

If the value of listname does not match the corresponding element in mongodb, it will return null

Comment: Yes, but I send request for listname : "Today" which exists in my DB , and i get the result but just before my result gives me `null` then the result, I don't know why it sends the `null` before sending me the list

Comment: mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema)，By default, it will carry s and become Tasks，Please check if there are Tasks in ATLAS?